How to implement a dependent radio form based on the answer of another radio form?
Extremely new to HTML/CSS/JS and looking to create a menu where you would select a radio button to specify a family of other radio options. If you click option A, then options 1-5 show up. If you click option C, then options 11-15 show up. Like this:  Example
                <form>
                    <div class="original-game-selector">
                        <input id="SNES" type="radio" name="console" value="SNES" />
                        <label class="console SNES" for="SNES"></label><br>
                        <input id="N64" type="radio" name="console" value="N64" />
                        <label class="console N64"for="N64"></label><br>
                        <input id="GBA" type="radio" name="console" value="GBA" />
                        <label class="console GBA"for="GBA"></label><br>
                        <input id="GCN" type="radio" name="console" value="GCN" />
                        <label class="console GCN"for="GCN"></label><br>
                        <input id="DS" type="radio" name="console" value="DS" />
                        <label class="console DS"for="DS"></label><br>
                    </div>
                </form>

That's about as far as I got. But looking to include this as the dependent:
                <form action="">
                    <div class="Courses">
                        <input id="SNES Bowser Castle 3" type="radio" name="course" value="Bowser Castle 3" />
                        <label class="course SNES-Bowser-Castle-3" for="SNES Bowser Castle 3"></label><br>
                        <input id="SNES Donut Plains 3" type="radio" name="course" value="Donut Plains 3" />
                        <label class="course SNES-Donut-Plains-3" for="SNES Donut Plains 3"></label><br>
                    </div>
                </form>

I haven't really tried much, I am extremely new to this and a Google search was not helpful.

I think you'll want to start by researching how to hide elements in CSS (probably using a class with the display property) and how to add event listeners to the radios to make something else happen

you can use js and get your element and change the innerHtml of that element on radio button change
